# GTM + Gravity Forms Goal tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a Gravity Form with a text confirmation page, not a redirect confirmation. I would like to track this form through Google Tag Manager to display a goal conversion in Google Analytics (Universal Analytics).

I've followed the steps here: http://www.notesonclick.com/blog/gravity-form-event-tracking-via-tag-manager/

No conversions are being recorded. However when using GTM-debug mode, all the triggers are firing, even the `gform.submit.success` tag is being fired after clicking the submit button.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

We've had the same issue. The only way we've been able to get GTM to record conversions is to remove validation. We'd rather it validate, but we haven't found any other workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I have implement that code in multiple site and it is working fine, Since you are not getting conversion then there might be issue with form Goal Creation in google analytics. or some time i have noticed this things happening when google analytics have been implement directly on the site and event tracking setup through tag manager..

if you still need some more help leave comment in comment box of same blog

Answer (score 0):

I saw the excellent and elegant solution by Dinesh but was not able to implement it on the site I was working with. I put a hack together that work correctly. For detailed instructions, please see here.
http://www.albanyanalytics.com/2018/03/gravity-form-tracking-with-google-tag.html

Comment: Please see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/266197 why link only answers are not great.

Comment: copy the information here kills all my pictures so the link works best here